# Fetch all objects having a specific empty RealmList property

Tags: android, realm

Today I moved to **Realm 0.83** and it is nice that we have null support but I have a problem.

I want to fetch all the stores that have empty products list inside. So far it worked if I used `isNull()` on the `RealmQuery` but since the update I get a crash like: `Illegal Argument: RealmList is not nullable.`

As it states in the crash, I cannot do this anymore because a `RealmList` is a `Required` field from now on so it can't be empty.. ok, that is nice but what can I use on the RealmQuery to fetch the models that I want?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by realm. You can now use [`isEmpty`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#isEmpty-java.lang.String-) and [`isNotEmpty`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#isNotEmpty-java.lang.String-) in the query builder for all RealmList properties.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I forgot to get back with an update :)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no option for doing that exact query anymore in 0.83.0. We think the improved `isNull` semantics are better, but it is very unfortunate that it is breaking current behaviour. I have created an issue for adding support back for this and hope to have it resolved very soon: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1601.

Right now you will have to work around it by manually iterating your data to find all objects that match your criteria.

Comment: Thanks for your support! Actually until we will have some support for that I used some not required properties of the items in the list to fetch the items that have empty lists of something. It is something like: isNull("listOfProducts.name") and of course I am making sure that the name will always be present in the product..